# Backpropagation (through convolutional layer) and gradients in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution, backpropagation

I am learning about using Convolutional Neural Networks and I went on to write my own framework for those.
I am stuck at the part where I have to backpropagate errors (deltas) through the network and calculate gradients. I am aware that the filters in CNNs are 3D, so we have width, height and depth of some filter.
Feed forward is fine. Let's look at the formula for calculating the output of some layer in feed forward step:

[image]

The depth of the filter in layer **l** should be the same as the number of output channels(depth) of output **z** of previous layer **l-1** in order to do convolution. So here, in this formula, we are convolving the output of previous layer and the weights of current layer and this works, since 3rd coordinate(depth) is equal in these two. Now, let's check the formula for backpropagation of errors:

[image]

In this one, we have the convolution of delta and weights array **w**, both from layer **l+1**. Now THIS is what confuses me, since in general their third coordinate(depth) is not always equal. Consider the VGGNet architecture and let's take a look at three consecutive layers in which the number of filters changes:

...

CONV3-128: [112x112x128]  memory:  112*112*128=1.6M   weights: (3*3*128)*128 = 147,456

POOL2: [56x56x128]  memory:  56*56*128=400K   weights: 0

CONV3-256: [56x56x256]  memory:  56*56*256=800K   weights: (3*3*128)*256 = 294,912

...

After the number of filters has increased from 128 to 256(in layer CONV3-256), it has the above mentioned dimensions of activation(and error delta) and weights. However, since the depth of filters(128 in this case) differs from 3rd dimension of its delta(256 in this case), how do I perform convolution of these 2 arrays? Thanks a lot to whoever helps. I find this confusing and I didn't find much help online in this area. It is mostly poorly explained or considered "known".

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the deltas and weights will not have equal depth. BUT THE NUMBER OF FILTERS IS EQUAL TO THE DEPTH OF DELTAS. 
I mean that you can have a filter of size (5x5x2) and deltas of size (20x20x4), but the catch here that indeed you will have FOUR filters.
You can check this by building a small CNN, you will see that the forwrad pass will not be valid unless this condition is true.